# Getting correctly aligned print export with OpenLayers plugin

Tags: qgis, export, printing

I am a beginner using QGIS (1.8.0 Lisboa) on a Mac (OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard). I work on a file with two layers in the following sequence (top to bottom):

- a vector polygon layer with a few outlines of various buildings in France and Italy (CRS: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - "on the fly" re projection is activated )
- a Google satellite layer uploaded via open layer plugin.

Sometimes when changing the scale (scrolling in and out) the Google layer updates a little wrong in size or position compared to the polygon layer. But as soon as I "pan" the map everything reconstructs right.
Now the problem I have concerns the print composer.

The result of any kind of export - pdf, or image or svg - of my map (vector layer + Google layer in the background) differs from what is shown in the preview of the print composer:
the vector layer and the Google layer positions are mismatching and in a different scale. I can send some pictures showing screenshots of the print composer preview and the final results if required.

I tried almost everything:

- new files with different CRS settings
- "cache" update preview
- "render" update preview
- different paper sizes,
- different scales,

The problem appears only using an open layer map (Google, OpenStreetMap...). If I try the same using two vector layer (shapefile) - one with the buildings, another one with the city in background - everything works out great.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this bug on 1.8, here are the related tickets: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4223 and http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6653

Testing with today's master, I cannot reproduce the problem anymore. Everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd share what worked for me. Like the OP I tried everything suggested on different threads about this issue with no success. The commonly suggested method to ensure the map layer is sized to the page dimensions didn't work for me either. Funnily enough, if I use "print as PDF" in the Print composer it gives me the correct version, align just like in the print composer window. I just double checked and "export as PDF" still gives me the old misaligned version.

Answer (score -1):

You can try http://mapproxy.org.

Mapproxy will make "open" layers available as a WMS server.