# Why does exported map from print composer differ from map canvas? QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-plugins, export, print-composer

I have a small project consisting of a Google maps satellite open layer with two new shapefiles overlaid on it. I have then used print composer to add a grid and some labels. I have also selected lock layers for map items and draw map canvas items in the map tab. However, when I come to import the exported map in to another document, the layers have shifted and the map has zoomed in to an offset position. This occurs in both pdf and image formats.
How do I ensure the map I produce in print composer does not alter when saved for export?

I hope someone can help as I have noticed another user asked [this same question back in February without any response (User 15214 on Feb 15th)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51986/pdf-export-mismatching-layers-and-scale-with-openlayers-plugin).
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is the map as shown in print composer http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/composer1_zpsc1416b54.png

Comment: And here is the map that is exported http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/composer2_zps4077abe6.png

Comment: @underdark, I am sorry for being dense here, but I cannot see an answer given to the duplicate of this question. That is why I have posted the question here. I have tried the links given in your edit but cannot see any answers only one question and a further comment?

Comment: Hi Ben, I've posted an answer to the older question now. It's not helpful for a Q&A site to have multiple versions of the same question open at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. I would not have posted my question if I had seen a previous answer. Now I can go away and sort out the problem. Cheers