# QGIS labels / MapQuest background

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling

I do have a problem with QGIS.
I Have to create a map which shows different areas in a city. It is important, that there are labels with names of the streets, so that my clients can work with the map. As Background Map I have to use MapQuest.
My problem now is, that the displayed Background in the Composer is different from the background which is exported (Composer: only motorways are labeled, exported: every street is labeled but so small, that nobody can read it.
I’m able to label the streets from an external source (OSM) but then there are both labels displayed, the small ones and mine, and this looks terrible.
So I think I have two options, first I can export the map without labels, so I can use my extra ones, second I have to reach, that the labels are exported bigger. (both I do not know if and how it is possible)
Does somebody have an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: I tried to reduce the dpi in the tab "composition" through this I reached, that the exportet background looks like the background in the composer.

Comment: so I can noch place the labels at the streets through extern data. But this works only until 115dpi (otherwise the resolution is high enought that qgis exports the names of the streets) so it is possible to work with that solution, but 115 dpi are not very much, especially for printing it in a big format

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with an old version of QGIS?

Even though I dont know your answer, maybe you will find an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51986/is-there-a-way-to-get-correctly-aligned-print-export-with-openlayers-plugin)

Comment: no I'm working with the latest version 2.14.1

Comment: unfortunately this posting do not focus on my problem, (I do have this Problem, too, but i solve it by making the map size the same as the page size.